# Custom action with Charge

Tags: plugins, plugin-charge

I'm trying to use a custom action with Charge. When a successful charge has been made I want to edit a user field. Charge appears to have Actions but little documentation on how they should be used ( http://demos.squarebit.co.uk/charge/actions )

So, I had opened charge/services/Charge_ActionsService.php and created a new one in there, which worked...

```
private function triggerActionCredits($details, ChargeModel $chargeModel)
{
    craft()->charge_log->action('Credits action triggered successfully');

    if (!is_array($details)) {
        craft()->charge_log->action("Details passed were: $details");
    } else {
        $detailsAsString = print_r($details);
        craft()->charge_log->action("Details passed were: $detailsAsString");
    }

    $userID = $chargeModel->userId;
    $theUser = craft()->users->getUserById($userId);
    $currentCredits = $theUser->creditsAvailable;

    craft()->charge_log->action("Got the user: $theUser");
    craft()->charge_log->action("Current credits: $currentCredits");
    craft()->charge_log->action("Details passed were: $detailsAsString");

    ... do stuff ...

    return true;
}
```

However, this should really be a plugin - so I've tried to port that code out of the Actions file and into its own plugin as follows:

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('charge.onCharge', function($charge){
        craft()->charge_log->action('Credits action triggered successfully');

        $pounds = $charge->amount;
        ...
}
```

The problem is that the line `$pounds = $charge->amount;` is throwing an error:

```
Property "Craft\Event.amount" is not defined
```

But; the event should be getting a Charge model? What am I doing wrong? http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/developer/hooks-and-events & http://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/models/charge-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
craft()->on('charge.onCharge', function($event)
{
    $charge = $event->params['charge'];

    $pounds = $charge->amount;
}
```